Find Galois closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$
Find Galois closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$

I know that the Galois closure of this is the splitting field of the polynomial corresponding to $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$. I can find at least two of the four roots of the minimal polynomial. So you start with $x=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ and manipulate this equation until you obtain $x^4-2x^2-1=0$.
Thinking backwards, it follows that two roots of $x^4-2x^2-1$ are $x= \pm \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$. If I could only find the two complex roots of this, I would know my Galois closure. What can I do at this point to find them?

The splitting field is $\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$, see this duplicate. It is Galois over $\Bbb Q$ with Galois group $D_4$.
